# How to implement a "private" method in Singleton class in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, singleton, private

I have a singleton MyClass in Objective-C.  In the singleton, let's say I have a method `-(void)foo` that other classes message using [`[MyClass sharedManager] foo]`.

In foo, I call a "private" method `-(void)bar` implemented in MyClass.  So something like this:

```
-(void)foo {
     [self bar];
}
```

Since I want bar to be private (as private as possible in Objective-C), I don't have the definition of bar in my MyClass.h file.  This causes a warning in XCode:

> Method '-bar' not found (return type defaults to 'id')

How do I have private methods in my singleton class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a "category". It is described here:
http://macdevelopertips.com/objective-c/private-methods.html

Basically you just declare the methods within the implementation file. Categories can be used for other things but this is a pretty simple way to use them.

The only thing I would change from the example code on that site, is that they have this at the top of the implementation file:

```
// =================================
// = Interface for hidden methods
// =================================
@interface SomeClass (hidden)
```

You should change it to:

```
// =================================
// = Interface for hidden methods
// =================================
@interface SomeClass ()
```

This makes it an "Anonymous Category". You don't need to name it because you are implementing the functions right here in the same file.

So if you want to declare a private method -(void)bar in your class you would do:

```
@interface MyClass ()
-(void)bar;
@end
```

Then you can implement this function like normal